# Backbone model empty after collection fetch

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller

```
var app = {};

var FoodModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "http://localhost/food"
});

var FoodCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FoodModel,
    url: "http://localhost/food"
});

var FoodView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    }
});

app.FoodModel = new FoodModel();
app.FoodCollection = new FoodCollection;
app.FoodCollection.fetch();


var myView = new FoodView({model: app.FoodModel})
```

In this piece of code, the console.log always returns null for data in this.model

If console.log the collection it is full of data, how can i get this.model inside the view to reflect the data in the collection?

Comment: What does the backend return?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your app is triggering `FoodView.render()`. It won't happen automatically when you instantiate `FoodView` and it won't happen when the json response triggers a callback to `app.FoodCollection.fetch()` unless you are manually calling that in a `success` callback. If you are doing this, your context may have been lost.

Also, there are a few typos in your code (`app.FoodCollection = new FoodCollection();`). If not, then can you provide the exact code? Please include whatever code is calling `render()`

Also, I'm not sure your view is being associated with your model. Try:

```js
var FoodView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: FoodModel,
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    }
});
```

Otherwise, Backbone has no way of knowing what model you are referring to.

Comment: This is wrong, first of all the model you are referencing is not instantiated, second the model is referenced when the view is created... var myView = new FoodView({model: app.FoodModel})

Comment: Not familiar with that pattern, but you passing the model into the constructor AFTER you call `app.FoodCollection.fetch()` so I'm not sure how the association would happen in time. But then it's not clear where `render()` is getting called from either. See my edit above asking for clarification.